# App store app submission issue in ios

Tags: ios, logging, crash

My app got rejected from app store with a reason that it **crashes on launch** screen. However, I've searched tremendously for any possibility that could cause the crash on launch, but unfortunately I am not able to reproduce the issue at all.

I've tried all steps mentioned by apple's team: symbolicated the crash logs, changed region of the device from India to US, tried keep the internet connection off/on while launching and so many things.

I have successfully uploaded more than 30 apps on app store and dealt with rejection several times... this time it is really killing me. I would really appreciate any help in this matter.

UPDATE

one thing I just noticed in the log: the app crashed when it was using 9.0.2 and now I've upgraded to 9.1 and it looks impossible to degrade again to 9.0.2 so is there any possibility that issue only occurs in **9.0.2** and if so, how can I resolve it without being able to reproduce it?

Comment: ask/submit your query to apple , those are give the screen shot and then check where it is occur

Comment: They provide me the crash logs not screen shots..apple team told that app is crashing on launch screen

Comment: then check your app in  without net connection once

Comment: No issue with internet on launch..cause app have static data on home screen

Answer (score 0):

You should analyze the crash reports before submitting the app to app store.

You can find the guidelines to submit crash reports in Apple's documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html